# view bag message not working properly on button click success using asp.net mvc?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

When i click on save button then success alert message is displayed, but i require only save function successful then only success alert message should be displayed.

In my code i written success alert message in button on click so it is not working properly. how to call `id="bn-success"` in view bag message on success.

```
<input type="submit" name="actionType" id="bn-success" value="Save" class="btn btn-rounded btn-inline btn-success" />
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Domain(Domain domain)
        {
            try
            {
                int refID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["RefID"]);
                if (ModelState.IsValid && refID > 0)
                {
                    userType type = new userType();
                    int id = type.AddDomain(domain, refID);
                    if (id != 0)
                    {
                        ViewBag.Message = "Domain added successfully";
                    }
                }
                return View();
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }

        }
```

Alert message:

```
 $('#bn-success').on('click', function() {
        $.notify({
            icon: 'font-icon font-icon-check-circle',
            title: '<strong>Heads up!</strong>',
            message: @ViewBag.Message
        },{
            type: 'success'
        });
    });
```

[image: Error]

Comment: Console errors? Async event on submit?

Comment: Yes  on save button then success alert message is displayed @mplungjan

Comment: If you need to submit the form, then you need to ajax and show the notify on successful return. If not, you need to preventDefault: `$('#bn-success').on('click', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); ..` if you want to see the notify

Comment: Not working sir@mplungjan

Comment: You need to make a few changes to achieve what you want. First you need to change your controller so it is not returning a view but something else when you post to it. It could be a bool to indicate success or failure. Then from the client side, you need to use ajax to post `Domain` object data to the controller and upon success call `$.notify`

Comment: okay sir your ajax method on success function is working good @CodingYoshi

Answer (score 0):

**'@ViewBag.Message'**

```js
$('#bn-success').on('click', function() {
    $.notify({
        icon: 'font-icon font-icon-check-circle',
        title: '<strong>Heads up!</strong>',
        message: '@ViewBag.Message'
    },{
        type: 'success'
    });
});
```

Comment: This will not fix the issue the OP is having. It will show the message as soon as the button is clicked.

Comment: Not Working sir